# Extracting or masking of very large raster to reduce file size on disk?

Tags: raster, r, clip, satellite, large-datasets

I have a very large 8-band raster (339806 x 61704) that I cannot load to memory to manipulate (R, raster:canProcessInMemory indicates I need 4999.16 GB of ram to load this file). However, I only need about 10% of this total area and I have a shapefile of the areas I need to keep.

**What is the most efficient way to load my areas of interest to memory?**

Masking of the original raster with my shapefile, or extracting my areas of interest and writing them to another raster (I need to retain the spatial reference of all of the sites)? Or some other process? I am new to this and prefer to use R if possible.

Comment: 10% of 4999Gb is still 500Gb. Have you got that?

Comment: Yes, I have 512 GB, although that may not allow me to perform any calculations on the extracted data. Maybe I would be better off splitting the raster into smaller tiles and processing each one individually.